# Is there a way to switch time based accounts for the same apps script project?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use my two google accounts for the same standalone project working at different times.

My project is not a webapp, it's a script that makes an api request and updates my sheet.

Account X is the owner, account Y is the second account. I have shared the project and the sheet with account Y, both as editors.

I'm using these functions

```
const times = new Date().getHours(); // get the current hour
```

```
const start = () => {load()}; // main function
```

```
const tX = () => {if ([12,13,14].includes(times)) {start();};} // run function from X account
```

```
const tY = () => {if ([22,23,0].includes(times)) {start();};} // run function from Y account
```

I created two other functions to set the triggers

```
function startX() {ScriptApp.newTrigger("tX").timeBased().everyMinutes(30).create();}
```

```
function startY() {ScriptApp.newTrigger("tY").timeBased().everyMinutes(30).create();}
```

With these settings I have to activate the startX function only once by logging with account X and then the startY function from account Y.

This script works, I would like to manage the two triggers from the owner account.

I have tried with

```
// Log the email address of the person running the script.
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);
```

[Class Session](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session?hl=it#getActiveUser()) didn't help me

Comment: installed triggers are run under the account that creates them. there is NO way for one account to create a trigger to run under a different account. See the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [`ScriptProperty`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#manage_script_properties_manually) to immediately exit if a switch is off.

Say, we have

Key: `X`
Value: 0

in Script Property. Then, we modify `tX` to use the switch:

```
const tX = () => {
  const switch = Number(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('X'))
  if (switch && [12,13,14].includes(times)) {
    start();
   };
} // run function from X account
```

Comment: I have a doubt, when it's a different time of 12,13,14, runs function from X?

Comment: @hub2sell If it's set to run from `X` and set to run every hour, `tX` runs every hour from ``X``, but `start` only runs at hours `12,13,14` and only when `switch` is `1`(or Truthy)